# Perform an action based on a check of pictures saturation

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 pictures that I am using to define teams in a round robin. When u click on one to indicate winner, the other one "greys out" with the following code

```
Sub W1One() 
Dim a As Shape 
Set a = ActiveSheet.Shapes("W1SeaEagles") 
a.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.05) 
End Sub
```

This however is not reversible, ie. in case I click the wrong one, i want to click the other one to perform the opposite reaction.
I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
Sub W1One() 
Dim a As Shape 
Dim b As Shape 
Set a = ActiveSheet.Shapes("W1SeaEagles") 
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes("W1Rabbitohs") 
If (a.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 100) Then 
    a.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.05 
    b.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 100 
Else: a.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 100 
    b.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.05 
End If 
End Sub
```

It doesnt work. The other picture (b) goes grey, but 'a' goes hypercolor!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting another saturation, you need to delete the existing saturation.

Let both pictures call the same macro W1One() and try this:

```
Sub W1One()
Dim a As Shape
Dim b As Shape
Set a = ActiveSheet.Shapes("W1SeaEagles")
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes("W1Rabbitohs")
If Application.Caller = "W1SeaEagles" Then
    With b.Fill.PictureEffects
        While .Count > 0
            .Delete (1)
        Wend
    End With
    a.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.05
Else
    With a.Fill.PictureEffects
        While .Count > 0
            .Delete (1)
        Wend
    End With
    b.Fill.PictureEffects.Insert(msoEffectSaturation).EffectParameters(1).Value = 0.05
End If
End Sub
```

Toggles the saturation just fine in my tests.